# How to extract everything after whitespace bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to read the first line of a text from a file and separate the first word from all other words so I can store the first word within a variable and all the other words within an array how would I do this my current script is listed below with the outputs I am getting and the desired outputs required.

```
  filename='currentTextFile.txt
  firstline=$(head -n 2 $filename)
  firstword=${line%% *}
  echo "$firstline"
  echo "$firstword"`


current input
168820245 firstName LastName DateOfBirth


current output
168820245 firstName LastName DateOfBirth
168820245

desired output
168820245
firstName, LastName, DateOfBirth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read` builtin:

```
read -ra arr < file

# first word
firstWord="${arr[0]}"

# remove 1st word from array
arr=("${arr[@]:1}")

# check output
declare -p firstWord arr
```

```
declare -- firstWord="168820245"
declare -a arr='([0]="firstName" [1]="LastName" [2]="DateOfBirth")'
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/DhT9ZN)

Comment: I tried to implement this but the firstWord is empty and is the 0th value within the array instead

Comment: I had a typo, fixed now. Check updated code and see working demo.

Comment: Another way to remove the first element from the array is `unset 'arr[0]'`.  The resulting "sparse array" needs special care though.